# Optimizing The Cost Per Bit Per Meter

Tags: routing, wan

I am working on a problem to minimize load for my thesis. 
Where the load is taken as the function of amount of traffic (bit) and length (m) to reduce the distance over which a demand is served.

My supervisor told me that this metric is widely used but I could not find any reference except for [this](http://www.commscope.com/Blog/optimizing-the-cost-per-bit-per-meter/) article.

How can I use this metric (bit-meter) to analyse communication network ?

Comment: Is your thesis specifically about optical networks or carrier fiber infrastructure (i.e. "Dark Fiber")?

Comment: "Know any paper or journal" is off topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here is a decent explanation from DrPeering.net](http://drpeering.net/AskDrPeering/blog/articles/Ask_DrPeering/Entries/2011/1/13_How_do_ISPs_cost_their_network.html) of the cost per bit-mile(meter).

> The Simple Bit-Mile Costing model tries to establish a network
>   component price per bit mile. This calculation might take all route
>   segments and calculate the average cost per mile. The end result would
>   be a $/bit mile cost number. Then gross traffic analysis would be
>   applied to see what a customer actually uses of the network bit mile
>   resources.
>
> For example, if a customer has 55Mbps of traffic from SFO to Seattle
>   (say 1200 miles) multiplied by the $/bit mile yields $X to carry that
>   traffic. The customer also has about 95Mbps from SFO to LA (say 400
>   miles) multiplied by the $/bit mile yields $Y to carry that traffic.
>   When taken in aggregate, one can get  sense of the order of magnitude
>   of the cost of this customer.

Also [here is Level3 peering agreement](http://www.level3.com/en/legal/ip-traffic-exchange-policy/) that talks bit-mile.  Level 3 seems to be one of the main carriers pushing for this.

So to be clear bit-mile costs are used for billing and peering agreements.  The bit-mile cost isn't a routing metric like hop count or bandwidth.

To minimize the bit-mile cost on your network, you would have to hack the bit-mile cost into the network some how.  The easiest way I can think is if you had a big OSPF network you could calculate all the bit-mile cost of all your links and statically configure them.  Then OSPF will calculate the route between locations using the lowest bit-mile cost.